# How to add Google Tag Manager to a NextJS13 website

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-tag-manager, next.js13

I want to add Google Tag Manager to my nextjs 13 app, the problem is there's no app.js file nor document.js file in nextjs 13.

I tried to use this solution: https://dev.to/valse/how-to-setup-google-tag-manager-in-a-next-13-app-router-website-248p

The google tag manager script gets detected but when I navigate to a new page google tag manager just adds another History Change or History and detect that a new page is being visited

[image]

Answer (score -3):

In Next.js 13, the file structure has been updated, and the approach mentioned in the article you referenced might not work as expected. However, you can still integrate Google Tag Manager into your Next.js 13 app by following a different approach. Here's a step-by-step guide to help you set it up

1. install gtm module
   npm install react-gtm-module
2. Create a new file called GTMScript.js in your Next.js project (you can place it anywhere in your project directory) and add the following code to it

import Script from 'next/script';

const GTMScript = ({ gtmId }) => (

{`
      (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j = d.createElement(s),
          dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
      })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', '${gtmId}');
    `}

);

export default GTMScript;

Comment: Ok and where will I import this function?

Comment: In your _app.js file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).